# LINQ Solution for the highest line with two or more same data

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have this situation:

```
Data: 28/11/2016 00:34:55 Idade: 20 Name:WSA
Data: 28/11/2016 00:34:55 Idade: 21 Name:WSA
Data: 09/08/2007 00:00:00 Idade: 10 Name:Wdddd
Data: 09/08/2007 00:00:00 Idade: 11 Name:Wdddd
```

I don't know how to resolve to pick the highest "Idade" value per Name, for the above example I need this as solution

```
Data: 28/11/2016 00:34:55 Idade: 21 Name:WSA
Data: 09/08/2007 00:00:00 Idade: 11 Name:Wdddd
```

Here's my code:

```
var persons = new List<Person>()
{
    new Person { Data = DateTime.Now, Idade = 20 , Name = "WSA" },
    new Person { Data = DateTime.Now, Idade = 21 , Name = "WSA" },
    new Person { Data = new DateTime(2007,08,09), Idade = 10 , Name = "Wdddd" },
    new Person { Data = new DateTime(2007,08,09), Idade = 11 , Name = "Wdddd" },
};

///TODO LINQ here
var _persons = from p in persons select p;

foreach (var item in _persons)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Data: {0} Idade: {1} Name:{2}", item.Data, item.Idade, item.Name));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `group by`:

```
from p in persons
group p by p.Name into grp
select grp.OrderByDescending(x => x.Idade).First();
```